# getting unfair "vote down" without any comment

Tags: support, privacy

Someone voted down my answers on these three posts by purpose and without leaving any comment, I flagged it but not sure if I can do something else as its same person keeps stalking my profile.

[How to restrict user to see only few rows in a list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43152/how-to-restrict-user-to-see-only-few-rows-in-a-list/43307#43307)

[Names of different sharepoint release](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40798/names-of-different-sharepoint-release/40803#40803)

for post above I posted a Image which was giving wrong information but then I removed it on explanation and don't find any reason for Vote Down.

[Connection between 2 web parts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43326/connection-between-2-web-parts/43331#43331)

I know the which account is doing this, as I can't block someone but can I make changes to my account or something so that they wont recognise me.

Also if someone can review my answers please.

Thanks

Comment: you cant "force" people to explain why they vote down. We generally encourage people to explain why they vote down (it costs them points, so there often is a good reason!)

Comment: I respect what you said, but my point is why would someone randomly look at answered I posted at random times and vote them down with difference of like 1 minute (I looked at timings)...
makes me think they didn't even read them properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an automated process that detects vote fraud. If there is a violation, the votes will be reversed.

We double checked just to be sure and so far there doesn't look to be a violation.

I wouldn't worry too much about it and I would recommend concentrating on posting great answers (see [How To Ask](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)). Other users can tell how much effort you put into an answer and upvote you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I revive this old post, because this has just happened to me to a [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/90339/8642) I posted recently.

I got two downvotes in reply to my downvotes on the two answers I got. It's a great let-down seeing such a puerile attitude and It's quite obvious to me who the downvoters were.

I think this epdisode clearly shows why we see so few vote casts here. If people take it personally and childishly respond to a downvote on an answer with a downvote on the question, I can imagine why community members refrain from casting votes altogether.

This, I think, defeats the whole purpose of the site.
I would have thought people here were more professional, but I made the mistake of underestimating the susceptibility of the human nature.

Comment: One a side note, the combination of low vote count and unmotivated downvotes makes the downvotes somewhat hurt more. Say you get 1 downvote and 1 upvote (sum: +8 points) here on SP.SE. On StackExchange the same question could have gotten 3 downvotes and 15 upvotes (sum: +146 points). So the fact that we have very low vote counts overall makes us more vulnerable to unmotivated downvotes

Comment: On the other hand, if I were to spend my time and give away my expertise for free on an answer, only to see the asker downvote it because it didn't quite solve his problem, I'd be a little discouraged by that too.

Comment: I downvoted not because it didn't solve my problem, but because it contained wrong information. It's different!! Don't we want to serve the community and anonymous users as well a good service, by helping them in discerning quickly what is correct from what is wrong ?

Comment: Let me clarify: there is a huge difference between "not helpful" and "wrong". And I want to add, my downvote on answers is perfectly in line with the spirit of SE. See this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/

Comment: It could be worse. I answered a question about conversational English over on the ELL SE, and had 6 people downvote my answer because they thought I was an arrogant American (simply because I didn't specify American English vs. British English in my answer, although I plainly said I'm from Texas). Thankfully, the behavior here hasn't reached that level.